# Python selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

within the website https://isapps.acxiom.com/optout/optout.aspx#section8 I want to access the field “Who is opting out?”. Using the logic of the post [Python Selenium webdriver: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60835480/python-selenium-webdriver-element-not-interactable-element-is-not-currently-vi) I tried following code
Version 1:

```
 ele2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='Identity']/option[@value='Myself']") 
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",ele2)
```

Version 2:

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='Identity']/option[@value='Myself']").click()

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "website-functions/acxiom.py", line 51, in <module>
    acxiom_DD_formfill(title, firstname, middlename, lastname, suffix, email)
  File "website-functions/acxiom.py", line 30, in acxiom_DD_formfill
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='Identity']/option[@value='Myself']").click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@id='Identity']/option[@value='Myself']"}     
  (Session info: headless chrome=80.0.3987.87)
```

This does not make sense to me since the id is indeed “Identity” (check at https://isapps.acxiom.com/optout/optout.aspx#section8).

Here is the full code I used:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os
import time
def acxiom_DD_formfill(title, firstname, middlename, lastname, suffix, email):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
    driver.set_window_size(1124, 850) # set browser size.
    # link to data delete form
    print("opening data delete form")
    driver.get("https://isapps.acxiom.com/optout/optout.aspx#section8")
    #Select opt out segment: Following option values: "Mail", "Telemarketing", "Email"
    ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='OptOutChoices2']/option[@value='Mail']") 
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",ele)
    print("dropdown selected")
    #Select identity: Following option values: "Myself", "Legal guardian", "Deceased person"
    #ele2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='Identity']/option[@value='Myself']") 
    #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",ele2)
    """Version 2"""
    #driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='Identity']/option[@value='Myself']").click()
    dropdown_optoutchoice=driver.find_element_by_id("'Identity'").location_once_scrolled_into_view
    dropdown_optoutchoice.select_by_value('Myself')
    # KEEP THIS DISABLED BC IT ACTUALLY SUBMITS 
    # driver.find_element_by_id("SubmitButton2").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    print("executed")
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.quit()
    return None
title="Mr"
middlename=""
firstname = "Joe"
lastname = "Musterman"
suffix=""
email = "joe@musterman.com"
acxiom_DD_formfill(title, firstname, middlename, lastname, suffix, email)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Check if the `//select[@id='Identity']/option[@value='Myself']` xpath is working in the chrome devtools. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870609/is-there-a-way-to-learn-xpath-without-using-firebug-or-xpath-as-firefox-is-not-s/55870909#55870909) post to know how to check xpath/css in the devtools.

Comment: Thank you, so version 2 seems to work for you but it yields the error above for me. Do you know how I could fix this with my code?

Comment: `//select[@id='Identity']/option[@value='Myself']` is using XPath 1.0 so you should see the same behavior.

Comment: Check the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer below solution to select value from dropdown box. You can pass your option value and select it using drop down.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://isapps.acxiom.com/optout/optout.aspx#section8")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='Identity']/option[contains(text(),'Who is opting out?')]"))).click();
```

Comment: @datasciencelearner : Can you please hit upvote button if its working for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct xpath.

```
//select[@name='Identity']/option[@value = 'Submitter']
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

`value` attribute value is `Submitter` not `Myself`, which is text of the option node. That's why you are getting the error.

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='Identity']/option[@value = 'Submitter']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",ele) # using js click so that item will be selected though it's not visible.
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! How can I then let selenium select the option "Myself"?